# How can I sort an ArrayList<HashMap<Integer, Boolean>>?

Tags: android, sorting, arraylist

In my MainActivity.java I have:

```
public static ArrayList<HashMap<Integer,Boolean>> booleanArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

public static void setBooleanArrayList(int p, Boolean b){
    HashMap<Integer,Boolean> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(p, b);
    booleanArrayList.add(map);
}
public static HashMap<Integer, Boolean> getBooleanArrayList(int position){
    return booleanArrayList.get(position);
}
```

I have a fragment which has a button. When the button is clicked I want it to sort MainActivity.booleanArrayList in ascending order.

For example:

```
{1,true}
{4,true}
{2,false}
{3,true}
```

sorted:

```
{1=true}
{2=false}
{3=true}
{4=true}
```

How would I go about sorting the ArrayList> once it is populated?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a List<Map<>> and not just a Map<>?  Maps have multiple entries in them, and in the data you're giving there's no reason to use a map.  In fact, if you need to sort them like this I'm not even sure a Map is the right structure, rather than a tree.

Comment: @GabeSechan how do i sort a treemap?

Comment: A search tree is sorted at insert time-  look into BSTs (binary search trees)

Comment: you can use `Pair<Integer,Boolean>` instead of `HashMap` and do `Collections.sort` your list easily.

Comment: Hi @Sebastian Zdroana, I think TreeHashMap will work for you. Please refer below link : 
https://dzone.com/articles/hashmap-vs-treemap-vs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 steps in doing that. First, write a Comparator that will compare 2 Maps:

```
public class MapKeyComparator implements Comparator<Map<Integer, Boolean>> {

        @Override
        public int compare(Map<Integer, Boolean> me, Map<Integer, Boolean> him) {
            Set<Integer> meSet = me.keySet();
            Set<Integer> himSet = him.keySet();
            // Sanity check
            if(me.size() != 1 || himSet.size() != 1){
                throw new RuntimeException("Comparison can only be done between 2 valid integers.");
            }
            // Values
            int meI = 0, himI = 0;
            for(Integer i : meSet){
                meI = i;
            }
            for(Integer i : himSet){
                himI = i;
            }
            // Compare
            if(meI > himI){
                return -1;
            }
            else if(meI < himI){
                return 1;
            }
            else{
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

And then, sort the list like below:

```
Collections.sort(booleanArrayList, new MapKeyComparator());
```

### Explanation:

Well, a `Comparator` is an interface that you can implement to compare 2 objects, say `Integers`. It can be any object in general but think about it, since it is comparison, it should make sense too comparing them. For ex, you wouldn't compare `Bird` object with a `Tree`. You can compare one `Bird` type with that of another because they have attributes that you can compare.

Now, in your case, we had to compare the Keys of the Maps present in the ArrayList. That means, the object to compare is a Map but based on what?

Well, you already know that - the Key of the Map. And, `Comparator` is an interface that facilitates just that.

So, we shall build a `Comparator` for comparing 2 Maps based on each Map's key. This `Comparator` in turn shall be used by the `Collections.sort()` method which takes a list of objects to compare and a `Comparator` to compare them.

Before we build the `Comparator`, lets see what the [Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) have to say about a `Comparator`.

> ```
> public interface Comparator<T>
> ```
>
> A comparison function, which imposes a total ordering on some
>   collection of objects. Comparators can be passed to a sort method
>   (such as Collections.sort or Arrays.sort) to allow precise control
>   over the sort order. Comparators can also be used to control the order
>   of certain data structures (such as sorted sets or sorted maps), or to
>   provide an ordering for collections of objects that don't have a
>   natural ordering.

And about the method you have to implement,

```
int compare(T o1, T o2)
```

> **Parameters**:
>
> **o1** - the first object to be compared.
>   **o2** - the second object to be compared.
>
> **Returns:**
>       a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

Notice that it says to return 1 if first object is greater than second. But I did the reverse in the implementation so that you can get a ascending arrangement instead of a descending one in `Collections.sort()`.

**The implementation:**

The implementation itself it pretty straightforward. Since I have to compare the keys from the Maps, I retrieve the keys in a Set:

```
Set<Integer> meSet = me.keySet();
Set<Integer> himSet = him.keySet();
```

Next, I check if they have a single element so that the comparison actually makes sense:

```
// Sanity check
if (me.size() != 1 && himSet.size() != 1) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Comparison can only be done between 2 valid integers.");
}
```

Next, I iterate the sets to get the one element present in both of them:

```
// Values
int meI = 0, himI = 0;
for (Integer i: meSet) {
    meI = i;
}
for (Integer i: himSet) {
    himI = i;
}
```

Next, we actually compare them,

```
// Compare
if (meI > himI) {
    return -1;
} else if (meI < himI) {
    return 1;
} else {
    return 0;
}
```

Also, see the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)) for `Collections.sort()` method.

---

Having said all that, there are other(better) things you can do for your basic problem like using a `TreeMap` which arranges the elements when you insert with the *natural ordering*. So when you retrieve them, you get them in the order you had always wanted. @ravi-koradia 's advice is spot on in terms of that and this article does a great job of explaining it:

https://dzone.com/articles/hashmap-vs-treemap-vs

Comment: This works but can you explain it please? Or point me in a right direction to a link which will explain it?

Comment: @SebastianZdroana : Give me a few minutes.

Comment: @SebastianZdroana : See the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Map, you can use your own custom class with position and selected value field, as I can see you need hold only these two value and every map of your list is having single value only.

```
public static ArrayList<Values> booleanArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

public class Values implements Comparable<Values>{
    int position;
    boolean isSelected;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Values values = (Values) o;

        return position == values.position;

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public int compareTo(@NonNull Values o) {
        return (position < o.position) ? -1 : ((position == o.position) ? 0 : 1);
    }
}
```

After that, you can call from anywhere to sort the arraylist:-

```
Collections.sort(booleanArrayList);
```

Comment: This may work but his design might have a different encapsulating unit(Class) including value, status and other things. In that case, this will erode the natural design.